# php script Bluehost Websocket server

Tags: websocket, bluehost, phpwebsocket

I'm trying to run a websocket server (php) but every time I call php-cli database.php (server file) I am given a new line and nothing happens. I try ps ax | grep websocket or database but I'm not seeing a process associated with the server. Can you help me out with running my script?  Also I'm a little confounded on formatting the addresses both clientside and serverside (I've been running my test scripts on Port 9000 as per websocket tutorial) but that is a question for another time... if anyone could help with these I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to add the -n switch, as per another post I don't have access to atm.  Calling "php -n database.php" ignores the libraries in Bluehost, which allows it to run properly.