# I am a bit confused about the use of WebSockets for auto updating websites

Tags: php, websocket

So I just watched [this little tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGCpm1H_kmA) on WebSockets and it makes sense, but for it to work, the websockets server file has to always be running, then users connect and messages are delivered to each other. However, I am confused on how this would be done on a website hosted with some hosting company, like Bluehost. As far as I know, you can't have a file always running on Bluehost, so how would this be accomplished? Or instead of having a file always running, for something like a chat where messages were saved into a database, would it be better to use something like long polling? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is correct that the server must be running continuously to support live webSocket connections.

As such, you have to select a hosting company that allows and supports that particular configuration.  Many of the cheapest shared hosting situations do not support that because their economics is based on the fact that your server isn't going to be running most of the time.

Here are some other answers on the topic:

[PHP Websocket on Bluehost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182900/php-websocket-on-bluehost)

[php script Bluehost Websocket server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871861/php-script-bluehost-websocket-server)

I don't know specifically about Bluehost, but some other similar companies require you to have a VPS (virtual private server) before you can run a the continuous server process needed to support long lived webSocket connections.